# Lazy<T, TMetaData> -> Lazy<dynamic, TMetaData> without instantiating?

Tags: c#, plugins, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

I use MEF and compose parts and get several `IEnumerable<Lazy<IFoo, IMetaData>>` (I have several imports). I like to merge all of the composed parts into one collection of type `IEnumerable<Lazy<dynamic, IMetaData>>`. Is that possible without invoking/instantiating the actual objects that implement IFoo or other interfaces?

I look to setup a large collection of composable parts but I do not like to instantiate them until they are actually requested. (Please see my related question: [MEF, why are identical duplicates of one and the same exported plugin created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415192/mef-why-are-identical-duplicates-of-one-and-the-same-exported-plugin-created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that by using something like:

```
from enumerable in enumerables
from lazy in enumerable
select new Lazy<dynamic, IMetaData>(() => lazy.Value, lazy.Metadata)
```

Unfortunately I do not have MEF at hand so please let me know if you will have any compilation problems. Note that `lazy.Value` is passed in a delegate and so not evaluated until needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solves my problem although I ended up accessing the container that comprises exported parts directly and thus I did not have to work with dynamics which makes the solution strongly typed. Thanks a lot